# ¿Cómo sumar los valores de una columna de una tabla?

Tags: javascript, php, sumatoria

Lo que quiero es sumar todos los valores de una columna PRICE y poder mostrarlos donde dice total.. alguno me puede ayudar con la formula que tendría que hacer para poder mostrar eso?

desconozco el código que tengo que poner ¿Cómo debería escribir el código?

Sé que para la mayoría será muy fácil mi pregunta, estoy aprendiendo :) gracias de antemano.

```
public function products($id){
        $data =Product::select('products.*','users.name as s_name')
        ->join('users','products.id_seller','=','users.id')
        ->where('products.id_subasta',$id)
        ->get();
        $all=[];
        $vendidos = 0;
        $noVendidos =0;
        foreach($data as $d){
            $buyer=Sell::select('users.name','users.phone','users.address','sells.price',
                'buyers.number','buyers.credit','sells.id as id_sell')
                ->join('buyers','sells.id_buyer','=','buyers.id')
                ->join('users','buyers.id_user','=','users.id')
                ->where('sells.id_product',$d->id)
                ->first();
                if($d->status == 0){
                    $vendidos+=1;
                }else{
                    $noVendidos+=1;
                }
            $all[]=[
                'id'=>$d->id,
                'product'=>$d,
                'buyer'=>$buyer];
        }
        $sub = Subasta::find($id);
        $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.products', [
            'img'=>$this->getLogo(),
            'data'=>$all,
            'subasta'=>$sub,
            'vendidos'=>$vendidos,
            'noVendidos'=>$noVendidos]);
```

[image: ahí esta la imagen quiero el resultado de la columna PRICE]

Ahí esta la imagen, quiero el resultado de la columna PRICE, quisiera saber como sumar todos los datos de una columna de mi base de datos.

Comment: El campo price que quieres sumar se encuentra en la tabla de productos o en la de ventas?

Comment: en la tabla de productos

Comment: Puedes traer el total directamente de la base de datos con la función `SUM(PRICE)`

Comment: como le hago soy nuevo en esto

Comment: Una pregunta, veo que en la tabla sells tambien tienes un campo price, ese campo tiene la el precio de los productos comprados? El cual es imagino el dato que quieres sumar, no es asi?

Comment: si asi es esa columna esa la que quiero el total